# How to find the Crashlytics version?

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I wanted to know wether I can able to find the Crashlytics version added in my existing project. And how ?

**Note*** 
Crashlytics has been added using "Fabrics" and added as submodules(not as pod).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply:

```
NSLog(@"Crashlytics version: %@", [CrashlyticsKit version]);
```

Or in Swift:

```
print("Crashlytics version: \(Crashlytics.sharedInstance().version)")
```

It returns a String like `3.7.3`

Comment: @Thank you, It worked. I was trying [Crashlytics version] and it was returning 0 all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Since **Firebase**/Crashlytics 7.1.0, it's:

```swift
FirebaseCore.FirebaseVersion()
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64883121/3783833

Answer (score 0):

You can also set debug to true. This gives you even more information, e.g. version of answers and fabric.sdk and if answers is disabled.

```
// Objective-C
[[Fabric sharedSDK] setDebug: YES];
[Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];

// Swift
Fabric.sharedSDK().debug = true
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self()])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import FirebaseCore

print(FirebaseCore.FirebaseVersion())
```

You can simply find the Crahslytics version by printing the FirebaseCore version. As it is noticed in the docs, their version is the same.
***Note:***

- You dont have to import `FirebaseCrashlytics` in the ViewController where you wanna print FirebaseCore's version
- You need to import `FirebaseCore` to print it, but no need to install the pod

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.